# Alignment inside the \align enviroment-horizontally and vertically

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align

Is it possible to make both expressions for omega's aligned with one another and do the same for the coefficients a,b,r and d,c,t? I tried to align them manually by using `center` but it does not work.

```
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{fouriernc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{align*}
 \omega_{1}^2&=1-2\sqrt[3]{19}+\sqrt[3]{19^2}\\
 \omega_{1}^{2}&=b\omega_{1}+a\omega_{2}+r
 \end{align*}  
 \begin{center}
 $a=3,\hspace{1cm}b=-3,\hspace{1cm}r=-3$
 \end{center}
 similarly
 \begin{align*}
 \omega_{2}^2&=\frac{1}{3}(13+7\sqrt[3]{19}+\sqrt[3]{19})\\ 
 \omega_{2}^{2}&=d\omega_{1}+c\omega_{2}+t
 \end{align*}
 \begin{center}
 $d=2,\hspace{1cm}c=1,\hspace{1cm}t=6$
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

I get something like this 
[image]

Is it possible to use align within `align` environment?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{fouriernc}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{align*}
 \omega_{1}^2&=1-2\sqrt[3]{19}+\sqrt[3]{19^2}\\
 \omega_{1}^{2}&=b\omega_{1}+a\omega_{2}+r\\
  a=3, & \qquad b=-3, \qquad r=-3  \\
 \shortintertext{similarly}
 \omega_{2}^2&=\frac{1}{3}(13+7\sqrt[3]{19}+\sqrt[3]{19})\\
 \omega_{2}^{2}&=d\omega_{1}+c\omega_{2}+t\\
 d=2, & \qquad c=1, \text{\phantom{$-$}}\qquad t=6
 \end{align*}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your solution looks better. Is it possible to push the third line in each system a little bit to the right?

Comment: yes. as you please you can shift the line either center or right or keep it left adjusted. It will not look nice if it is centered.

Comment: @user124471 Pushed now. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code could be written as shown below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{fouriernc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{align*}
 \omega_{1}^2&=1-2\sqrt[3]{19}+\sqrt[3]{19^2}\\
 \omega_{1}^{2}&=b\omega_{1}+a\omega_{2}+r
 \end{align*}  
 \flushright
 Where
 $a=3,\hspace{0.8cm}b=-3,\hspace{0.6cm}r=-3$\\
 \vspace{0.3cm}
  \flushleft
  Similarly
 \begin{align*}
 \omega_{2}^2&=\frac{1}{3}(13+7\sqrt[3]{19}+\sqrt[3]{19})\\ 
 \omega_{2}^{2}&=d\omega_{1}+c\omega_{2}+t
 \end{align*}
\flushright
Where
 $d=2,\hspace{1cm}c=1,\hspace{0.9cm}t=6$

 \end{document}
```

OUTPUT:

[image: alignvh]